# PHP api getUser() returns 0 after some time

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using both the JS & PHP SDK. After a user of mine visits the landing page, the FB session is set, that's what I think happens at least.

After a page reload the user ID will be returned using the function $facebook->getUser(). So I guess this means the PHP SDK found a cookie? Anyway, after 10 min or so (I'm not really sure what the timeframe is for this) , when I run the same function it returns 0! Very annoying.

How long should the session last?

As a temporary solution I'm calling getLoginStatus() on the client side. This reactivates the session.

Does anyone else have this problem?

**update**

I think it might be this bug..
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/406997072723008

Comment: Have you tried extending the access_token and seeing if it works? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: No, I've been thinking about it, but I'm not sure how I should store it. But still, there is states: "by default the token is only valid for one to two hours."

Comment: Right, it shouldnt be the problem but its a step in the elimination process. It could be a problem with cookies, etc. As far as storing it, you'd use a Database

Comment: What happends after the sixty days when it expires And will I need any extra permissions for that?

Comment: You will need them to redirect the user to the login dialog again, it will notice they have already accepted the app, and will redirect back to your app with a new `code`. It's the same process as sending someone to the dialog for the first time. This process, while it might seem annoying to you as a developer, helps keep spam and unwanted app actions off of Facebook. You should keep track of the expiration date and send an email to the user when they need to login to keep the app going.